# TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, windows-server-2008-r2

In Sql Server2008 R2 and Windows Server 2008R2, when I start Replication I have this error:

> TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Do a web search on "TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired". There are many results which explain what's happening and with various possible solutions.#

Comment: We Use Merge Publication & "pull subscription "  ,This error was appeared recently ,

Comment: Fine. So go read the many links a se arch will provide you with and see what you can find out and try. Come back with what you've tried and what happened. We don't do your research for you, I'm afraid.#

Comment: OK,i read some link for Example [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942861] but, it didn't work

Answer (score 6):

in order to fix the error:

> System.IO.IOException: The semaphore timeout period has expired.

**​Solution​**

I have done below NIC changes to resolve this error.

1. Open the Network and Sharing Center.
2. Right click on Ethernet Adapter>>Properties
3. Select Client for Microsoft Networks
4. Click on **Configure** Tab
5. Click on **Advanced** Tab
6. And then - **Disable the below settings**

   - IPv4 Checksum offload
   - Large Send Offload V1(Ipv4)
   - Large Send Offload V2(Ipv4)
   - TCP Checksum Offload(IPv4)
   - UDP Checksum Offload(IPv4)

**After disabling the above settings; it resolved our Semaphore error.**

Comment: hi - where do you this ? in the publisher and/or subscriber ?

Comment: You can do this on the machine on which you are getting the error.

Comment: No explanation of why? Did you just randomly start disabling options?

Comment: Great answer. You just need to disable Large Send Offload, TCP checksum and UDP checksum for IPv6 too