# Azure SQL: provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired

Tags: sql-server, azure, windows-server-2012-r2, transient-failure

It's similar to this question, but it contains no fix: [TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410270/tcp-provider-the-semaphore-timeout-period-has-expired)

I am using the enterprise lib transient fault handling (v 6.x) with a retry policy. I have used it for years and this error is a new one. Perhaps due to Windows update on our webserver (win 2012r2)

So since there is no C# code changed and I am using the enterprise lib for ages... it must be windows/hardware related?

I have found this, saying it's [winsock related](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d99b4d8e-feeb-43cb-80af-3d4826340a2c/the-semaphore-timeout-period-has-expired?forum=sqldataaccess) and some source about usb drivers?

There is a [known issue with vip swaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26762061/169714), but we are running the webapps (both webforms and mvc apps have this issue) from our own on prem 2012r2

Here is one of the stacktraces:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
Shop.Dal.DB.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<GetDatatable>b__0()
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteAction>b__0()
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
Shop.Dal.DB.GetDatatable(SqlCommand com) The semaphore timeout period has expired
```

Comment: I had this error the other day and it quite simply required a firewall change (sorry don't know what exactly). I got a whole range of errors quite different to the usual connection ones but they were all resolved with a firewall change.

Comment: Maybe posting it on https://serverfault.com/ will yield some results? Make sure you explicitly state that this question is double posted if you going to do this.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid also had win2012r2? and azure db? Using entity lib nuget for data access.